# failed to start daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, contains

I start docker

```
sudo service docker start
```

then I try to run dockerd

```
sudo dockerd
```

it shows the following error:

> INFO[2021-11-21T19:25:52.804962676+05:30] Starting up
> failed to start daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid

Comment: The docker service starts the docker daemon = dockerd. If you want to interact with the docker daemon, you need to use `docker`.

Comment: ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.

Comment: have you tried deleting `/var/run/docker.pid`?

Comment: I try this it works for me. Thanks.
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock

Answer (score 10):

Delete the .pid file using the below Linux command,

```
rm /var/run/docker.pid
```

Now the pid file will get deleted and the docker daemon can be launched newly.

Comment: Worked with `rm /var/run/docker-ssd.pid`.

Comment: works for me!! this should be voted up

Answer (score 4):

it works for me:

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: Do this carefully!  If you can access the Docker socket, you can `docker run -v /:/host busybox cat /host/etc/shadow` to see (or edit!) the host's encrypted password file, and otherwise trivially root the host.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the PID file. Kill the running docker service and start it again.

```
ps -ef | grep docker
kill -9 <PIDs>
sudo systemctl start docker.service
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The following worked for me:

1. Deleted `/var/run/docker.pid`
2. Reboot computer

Answer (score 1):

```
Had similar issue
`sudo docker ps -a`
```

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

`sudo systemctl status docker`

docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: deactivating (stop-sigterm) since Wed 2022-09-07 09:32:11 -05; 5h 55min ago
Docs: https://docs.docker.com
Main PID: <PID_NO> (dockerd)
CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
└─<PID_NO> /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

```
 time="2022-09-07T09:32:26.-05:00" level=info msg="ccResol...=grpc
 time="2022-09-07T09:32:26.-05:00" level=info msg="ClientC...=grpc
 time="2022-09-07T09:32:26.-05:00" level=info msg="pickfir...=grpc
 time="2022-09-07T09:32:26.-05:00" level=info msg="pickfir...=grpc
 time="2022-09-07T09:32:26.-05:00" level=info msg="[graphd...lay2"
 time="2022-09-07T09:32:26.-05:00" level=warning msg="moun...ound"
 time="2022-09-07T09:32:26.-05:00" level=info msg="Loading...art."
systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.
systemd[1]: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
dockerd[<PID_NO>]: time="2022-09-07T09:39:52.-05:00" level=info msg="Process...ted'"
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.


 
`sudo systemctl start docker`  -- Gives no output 

deleted docker.pid file in var/run but It didn't helped either
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you're trying to start docker pid and getting this error:-

```
INFO[2023-05-03T12:13:55.369754816+05:30] Starting up failed to start daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid

systemctl stop docker
```

> After that just delete the docker.pid file

```
rm /var/run/docker.pid
```

> And then just run `sudo dockerd` and you good to go

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I ran `sudo service docker stop` and it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem, and this is my resolve:

1. the problem: docker is hang, even i try to stop with:

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
```

2. then i try to debug with:

```
sudo dockerd --debug
```

showing:

```
INFO[2024-01-06T09:49:56.628001335-05:00] Starting up                                  
failed to start daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid
```

3. and try to remove the pid file with:

```
rm /var/run/docker.pid
```

it should be fix your problem